# compare two files in UNIX

Tags: unix

I would like to compare two files [ unsorted ]
file1 and file2. I would like to do file2 - file1 [ the difference ] irrespective of the line number?
diff is not working.

Comment: Have you considered sorting and then comparing?

Comment: Diff is not working? Diff should work. what's the error?

Comment: Not programming... Move to superuser.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I got the solution by using comm

```
comm -23 file1 file2
```

will give you the desired output.

The files need to be sorted first anyway.

Comment: According to [`comm` man page](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?comm++NetBSD-current), it works on lexically sorted files. Thus, you will have to use `sort` on your files first.

Comment: Like indicated by [amalloy's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715885/compare-two-files-in-unix/4756123#comment24120178_4715952) for `diff`, you can also say `comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`.

Answer (score 27):

Well, you can just sort the files first, and diff the sorted files.

```
sort file1 > file1.sorted
sort file2 > file2.sorted
diff file1.sorted file2.sorted
```

You can also filter the output to report lines in file2 which are absent from file1:

```
diff -u file1.sorted file2.sorted | grep "^+"
```

As indicated in comments, you in fact do not need to sort the files. Instead, you can use a process substitution and say:

```
diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Comment: By the way, bash has a shortcut for the first three commands together: `diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`.

Answer (score 4):

There are **3** basic commands to compare files in unix:

1. `cmp` : This command is used to compare two files byte by byte and as any mismatch occurs,it echoes it on the screen.if no mismatch occurs i gives no response.
   syntax:$cmp file1 file2.
2. `comm` : This command is used to find out the records available in one but not in another
3. `diff`

Comment: to add on top of this, cmp is used only on sorted data.

Answer (score 2):

Most easy way: sort files with sort(1) and then use diff(1).