# Maven Pom update difference in dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I have a pom file with multiple dependencies(spring boot, hibernate etc.) When I change version of one of them, many others are updated, such as hamcrest. Is there any way to track, what are the changes which occur when You change the version of Your dependency? For example when You change the version of spring-boot-dependencies, You can see that there is a possibility to change the hamcrest or jackson version.

Comment: check the mvn : dependency tree  output to see the clear picture of your effective pom

Comment: However, I want to see what packages were updated for example in my last change of versions in dependencies.

Comment: share the pom and what exactly you are changing.

Comment: You could create a visual representation of both versions and compare it https://github.com/ferstl/depgraph-maven-plugin

Comment: If you are working with Spring Boot the best is simply to change only the version of your spring-boot parent or the BOM file but don't handle all dependencies like hamcrest, hibernate etc yourself cause Spring Boot already does that correctly.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is I run `mvn dependency:tree` before making the change. Save the output to a text file, then make the change and run the same command. Save that output to another text file.

You can then compare the two however you'd like. [compare two files in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715885/compare-two-files-in-unix)